# spring REST message bus communication

Tags: spring-mvc, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am looking for spring module that can help me to integrate spring REST web services with message bus(RabbitMQ). REST web service are acting as a consumer of AMQP messages from the client. Whenever messages are sent over the bus it is an AMQP message and to make it work with REST, it has to be converted in to REST call. Is anyone aware of the existing solution to make it work?

Comment: Are you trying to use an REST-api provided by Rabbit Mq to get messages. (http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html). Or trying to create your own client that will receive messages and expose them as REST call to other clients.

Comment: I am not using the REST service provided by RabbitMQ. Trying to create my own service, want to keep REST interface independent of whether I am using message bus or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't see the value in this i.e. using a synchronous REST interface to consume some a-synchonous AMQP messages as you are kind of losing the purpose / advantages of an a-synchonous message system like RabbitMQ.

The great thing about AMQP is that it's a wire protocol and not tied to one language (e.g. JMS is pretty much tied to Java).  This means you could use Java / Spring / AMQP library, Node.JS / AMQP library, C# / AMQP library etc.  This article explains the advantages better than me http://www.wmrichards.com/amqp.pdf  My point is, if you're looking for REST to create a bridge between another language / system etc to RabbitMQ then I would first of all investigate if the other language / system supports an AMQP library.

However, if you MUST have a REST'ful interface you could create a simple controller using SpringMVC and inject a `private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;` with some methods.  This effectively creates your REST-to-AMQP bridge / proxy.  The spring configuration / Java Controller is as follows (note this has been tested and works): -

*/spring/restAmqpContext.xml*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

<!-- Location of "config.properties" to override RabbitMQ connection details if required. -->
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" 
                              location="classpath:/config.properties,
                                        ${DATA_HOME:}/config.properties"  />

<bean class="com.bobmarks.controller.RestAmqpController">
    <property name="amqpTemplate" ref="amqpTemplate"/>
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactory" 
                           host="${rabbitmq.host:localhost}" 
                           port="${rabbitmq.port:5672}" 
                           username="${rabbitmq.username:guest}" 
                           password="${rabbitmq.password:guest}"
                           publisher-confirms="${rabbitmq.publisher.confirms:true}" 
                           publisher-returns="${rabbitmq.publisher.returns:true}" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" mandatory="true" />

<rabbit:admin id="rabbitAdmin" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="my_queue" />
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="my_exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings><rabbit:binding queue="my_queue" key="my_binding" /></rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

*RestAmqpController.java*

```
package com.bobmarks.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

/**
 * Simple Rest To AMQP Controller.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest2amqp")
public class RestAmqpController {

    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    public RestAmqpController() {}

    public void setAmqpTemplate(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        this.amqpTemplate = amqpTemplate;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> message(@RequestParam(value = "message") String message) {

        try {
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("my_exchange", "my_binding", message);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Message sent to AMQP queue at: " + new Date(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (AmqpException amqpEx) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(amqpEx.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

These are packaged up in the usual way (Tomcat / Spring Boot / etc) and for example if the project is called *data* the REST endpoint to send a message would be as follows: -

http://localhost/data/rest2amqp?message=Hello_World

This is probably better shown with screenshots.

*Screenshot of submitting message (just using FireFox)*
[image: REST Endpoint to add message]

*Screenshot of RabbitMQ Admin Client showing message arrived*
[image: RabbitMQ showing queued message]

*Screenshot of actual message*
[image: RabbitMQ message details]

**NOTE:** This is a very basic example with a single RabbitMQ exchange / queue and doesn't contain security or any of the other basic stuff you would probably want!